# How can I duplicate an EVP_PKEY struct without knowing the underlying algorithm?

Tags: c, openssl

I'm working on a TLS implementation (using OpenSSL 1.0.1s) that currently employs 1024-bit RSA keys for both encryption and authentication. I want to upgrade to EC for performance reasons, but I need to remain backward compatible.

So I decided to use OpenSSL's EVP API to have as much common code as possible. But, I've run into a problem when I want to read certificates from my RAM (stored in ASN.1 DER format), I can't find a way to completely copy an `EVP_PKEY` struct (no `PKEY_dup` or `PKEY_copy` or anything of the sort).

I want to avoid switch-casing the `EVP_PKEY.type` so the next upgrade will be smoother, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to duplicate by converting to DER and back. the general i2d/d2i functions call the specific ones.

Code:

```
error_code_ENUM read_evp_pkey_from_ram (int       index,
                                        int       DB_ID,
                                        EVP_PKEY  **pkey_ptr_PTR){
  EVP_PKEY           *pkey;
  unsigned char      *p;
  unsigned char      *DER_PTR;
  int                DER_size;
  int                pub_len, priv_len, type;

  *pkey_ptr_PTR = NULL;

   if ((pkey = sensitive_EVP_PKEY_data[DB_ID][index]) == NULL)
     return error_code_no_key;

   type = pkey->type;
   /*passing NULL to char *out returns the length only*/
   pub_len = i2d_PUBKEY(pkey, NULL);
   priv_len = i2d_PrivateKey(pkey, NULL);
   if (pub_len <= 0 || priv_len <= 0 )
       return error_code_general_error;

   DER_size = pub_len + priv_len + 2 * sizeof(UINT_16);
   if ((DER_PTR = OPENSSL_malloc(DER_size)) == NULL)
       return error_code_no_memory;

   /* 
    * store the key in buffer as:
    * |public key length | public key | private key length | private key|
    */
   p = DER_PTR;
   *(UINT_16*)p = pub_len;
   p += 2;
   pub_len = i2d_PUBKEY(pkey,&p);/*p is incremented here by the key size*/
   *(UINT_16*)p = priv_len;
   p += 2;
   priv_len = i2d_PrivateKey(pkey,&p);


   p = DER_PTR + 2;
   /*pass NULL to EVP_PKEY *key causes a fresh EVP_PKEY struct to be allocated and a pointer to it returned*/
   pkey = d2i_PUBKEY(NULL, (const unsigned char **)&p, pub_len);
   if (pkey == NULL){
      OPENSSL_free(DER_PTR);
      return error_code_general_error;
   }

   priv_len = *(UINT_16 *)p;
   if (priv_len == 0){
       EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
       OPENSSL_free(DER_PTR);
       return error_code_general_error;
   }

   p += 2;
   /*now pass &pkey*/
   if (d2i_PrivateKey(type, &pkey, (const unsigned char **)&p, priv_len) == NULL){
          OPENSSL_free(DER_PTR);
           return error_code_general_error;
        }

   OPENSSL_free(DER_PTR);

   *pkey_ptr_PTR = pkey;

   return error_code_no_error;
```

note that i2d/d2i functions increment the pointers they are given

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your problem, you can try to use [`EVP_PKEY_up_ref()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_PKEY_new.html) (that increments `EVP_PKEY` reference counter) and then pass the pointer to the original `EVP_PKEY`. This way you can safely use `EVP_PKEY_free()` then (which  decrements the counter first and only really frees when it becomes zero).

Comment: up_ref doesn't solve my problem since I require a completely different copy